A random variable X is N(25, 4). Find the indicated percentile for X:
I am tring to find the solution for below question but my result is not matching with the internal validation and it's falling everytime.
Question:  A random variable X is N(mean=25, SD= 4). Find the indicated percentile for X. All the answers are expected to be rounded off to two decimal places.
a. The 10th percentile
b. The 90th percentile
c. The 80th percentile
d. The 50th percentile
I am getting below response after executing my code
import scipy.stats as sts
mu_new = 25  # Mean 
sigma_new = 4  # Standard deviation 

# The 10th percentile
p10 = round(sts.norm.ppf(0.1, loc=mu_new, scale=sigma_new), 2)

# The 90th percentile
p90 = round(sts.norm.ppf(0.9, loc=mu_new, scale=sigma_new), 2)

# The 80th percentile
p80 = round(sts.norm.ppf(0.8, loc=mu_new, scale=sigma_new), 2)

# The 50th percentile
p50 = round(sts.norm.ppf(0.5, loc=mu_new, scale=sigma_new), 2)

print(p10)
print(p90)
print(p80)
print(p50)


My OutPut:
19.87 
30.13 
28.37 
25.0

I have also read an article very similar to this problem but the test cases are still falling after using solution from this page :
How to compute the percentiles from a normal distribution in python?
When I am running my solution in the graded system, I am getting below error:
incorrect answers p90, p80, p10
Please help on this?

I didn't calculate the exact values, but what you get seems reasonable. What are the expected values? And maybe more importantly if you provide the output to some automatic grading system, are you sure of the expected output format? The output you show can't be the one from your code, as it would print all values on one line separated by spaces, not on different lines. Please clarify.

corrected my question, pls check.

Well, you didn't address my comment. The values are correct (I checked), but you didn't answer my question about the expected format, neither why your supposed output can't be the output of the code you show here.

i have checked internally with other persons, they said, the correct answer is as below:
a_9 = 19.88  #right ans
b_9 =30.12   #right ans
c_9 = 28.36  #right ans
d_9 = 25.0   #right ans
but i dint understand how this values quite different to my answer?

What "other persons" gave you for "valid answers" are incorrectly rounded.

yeah, you're right, but when i am putting right rounded values the test cases are falling.  But when I am manually providing the incorrected rounded values the test cases are passing. LoL
